# Find the $\angle FPA$ in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, planar-graphs

For reference: Starting from a point $P$, outside a circle the tangent $PA$ and the secant $PQL$ are drawn. Then join $L$ with the midpoint $M$ of $PA$.
LM intersects at F the circle.
Calculate $\angle FPA$ if $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{QF}=72^o$
[image]

My progress:

$\angle FAP = \theta=\angle ALM$ (alternate angles)

$\triangle AOF$(isosceles) $\implies \angle OAF = \angle AFO=90-\theta$

$\angle AOF = 2\theta$

I'm not seeing the other relationships...???

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\angle PLM = 36^\circ$

Also using power of point $M$, $~MA^2 = MF \cdot ML = PM^2$

$$ \implies \frac{PM}{FM} = \frac{ML}{PM}$$

and given $\angle PML$ is common,
$$\triangle PLM \sim \triangle FPM~~ \text {(by S-A-S rule)}$$

That leads to $~\angle FPM = \angle PLM = 36^\circ$

Comment: One question..Shouldn't $PL$ be tangent to $\angle PLM=36^o$?

Comment: @petaarantes no, do you see that $\angle FLQ = 144^0$?

Comment: What is this property of the angle opposite the central being double in the quadrilateral $OFLQ$?

Comment: What is the angle arc $FQ$ subtends at circumference opposite $L$? $~36^\circ$, right? So, $\angle FLQ = 180^0 - 36^0$.

Comment: Now I understand.. I had alternates angles in my mind (which was the case of the theta angle) and that's why I was confusing..gratitude

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In figure circle S is circumcircle of triangle APF. AQ is perpendicular on radius AS.In circle S angle APF is opposite to arc AF, the measure of arc AF is $72^o$ because it is opposite to angle QAF and we have:

$\angle QAF=\frac {72}2=36^o \Rightarrow \overset{\large\frown}{AF}=72^o$

and QA is tangent on circle S at vertex A.

So the measure of angle APF is:

$\angle APF= \frac{72}2=36^o$

Comment: You are welcome.